# Trouble with importing pygame with pip

Tags: pygame, python-3.8

I have installed pygame but I get traceback errors @import pygame, this is the error :
Traceback (most recent call last) :
     File "c:/users/USER/Desktop/my programs/Alien Invasion l/alien_invasion.py",
 line 3, in 
         import pygame 
    File "c:/users/USER/Desktop/my programs/Alien Invasion l/alien_invasion.py",line 95, in 
         from pygame.base import*
Import error: DLL load failed while importing base: The specified module could not be found.
Do you think it's because my python version is not the same with my pygame version. 
I also tried typing 
`python -m pip install -U pygame -user`
But I got ' python is not an internal or external command, operable program or batch file, I need this to continue my learning, please help me out

Comment: How did you install pygame? Using pip? please be more specific and maybe show us some error code. Thanks!

Comment: Add what have you tried and error details

Comment: Which os are you using?

Comment: I'm using windows 7, 32 bit OS

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error messages you are getting, it will make it a lot easier for us to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to your python IDE,  then click open
2. when you click on the open,  at the top (that is the open file window) click the place where you see the python path for example when you're in your document folder, at the top you will see: user/name/document. Click that place in the open window, then type cmd after that press the enter key. It will open the command prompt, type:python -m pop install -U pygame -user,  and that's all